# How can I create a new MODx context programmatically?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'd like to quickly create a whole bunch of contexts. How can I programmatically create new contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Load the MODx object as described at http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/loading-modx-externally, then use `modX->runProcessor` to run the 'context/create' processor.

```php
<?php
require_once '/absolute/path/to/modx/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'model/modx/modx.class.php';
$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('web');
$modx->getService('error','error.modError', '', '');
$modx->runProcessor('context/create', array(
    'key' => 'newcontext',
    'name' => 'New Context',
    'description' => 'No description.'
));
```

Thank you unit test. https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/cd690b16c303823697562c89efb1a8b2045bc429/_build/test/Tests/Processors/Context/ContextTest.php#L80-L83